# bash command clubbing: get specific command's exit status

Tags: bash, shell

I've a command clubbing of 3 commands as below.

```
do A && do B || undo A
```

Here if `do A` fails, it'll return with non-zero exit status. If it succeeds, it goes to `do B`. If `do B` succeeds, it is zero exit status which is expected. But if it fails, it goes to `undo A` which succeeds and `do B`'s exit status (which in this case will be a non-zero) is lost which shows the actual failure. So the whole commands exit status will be 0 though there is a failure.

Any way is it possible to get the `do B`'s exit status in the above statement?

I know this can be easily done with `if else`. I'm just curious about a one-liner.

Comment: You can write a one-liner with `if else` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need `B`'s exact error code, you can return an error code explicitly by invoking `/bin/false`, or bash's builtin `false`:

```
do A && do B || ( undo A && false )
```

Otherwise, you can store the exact error code and return that value, although that is a bit ugly as a one-liner:

```
do A && do B || ( CODE=$? ; undo A; exit $CODE )
```

The above works by spawning a [subshell](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) using parantheses.

Comment: `do A && do B || ( CODE=$? ; undo A; exit $CODE )` will also `undo A` if `do A fails`. You have to use curly braces to prioritize the boolean. You wrote A × B + C rather than A × ( B + C ). Fixed version is do `A && { do B || ( CODE=$? ; undo A; exit $CODE )}`